# SwiftUI: Is it possible for a document-based app to display a custom view instead of the file picker?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have just started learning swift and I am writing a document-based app. By default, when launching the app without opening any document with it, a file picker would appear.

Is it possible for it to skip the file picker, and display a custom greeting window if no file is opened with the app? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can, no one is limiting you to do so, setting your own view controller as an entry point.

Demo: [Github](https://github.com/kasimok/docTest)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe your code is how it's done with Cocoa right? Is there any way of doing it with SwiftUI?

Comment: for swiftUI Refer to :  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653474/how-to-make-a-swiftui-documentgroup-app-without-starting-on-the-file-picker